# How to insert selected item text from checkedlistbox to gridview dynamically in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My requirement is, i have a checkedlistbox, and i want the selected item should be inserted into the gridview using javascript, in grid i want only two columns i.e. selected item text and another is checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the following link it will help you up.

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article971-aspnet-gridview--jquery-tips-and-tricks--part-2-.aspx